# Creating unique Key as FK - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I've an endpoint `/user` which creates an unique UUID for a user. It inserts the data(phoneno, gender, age) into the table(cassandra table) and then forwards the same data to another server along with the user_id just created, having MYSQL as the DB.

Now in my MySQL the table is as follow.

```
id(varchar)
phone no
age
gender
etc.
```

But I've read that using VARCHAR as PK is a very bad solution. Hence I modified my table as follow:-

```
id(interger auto increment)
user_id (varchar unique)
phone no
age
gender
etc.
```

I have another endpoint `/recharge`, which contains the `user_id (UUID), recharge_amount, operator, etc.`.

My recharge table is as follow:-

```
user_id FK
amount
operator
```

Now the problem arises that whenever I'll receive the data for `/recharge` I need to get the respective id of the user from the Users table to reference it in the recharge table, which is an extra operation. ie for every insert, there will be an extra read operation.

Can I reference/use the unique key as my FK in the recharge table. **If no, then what can be the possible solution?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use unique key as foreign key.
To use a column as FK in other table it has to be a PK or a Unique Key.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. From various blogs, I've read that using VARCHAR as PK is a very bad solution, as it lowers down the write speed if the records are over a million and in my case it will be. It lowers the speed because it need to rearrange the index and various other things. But how about using VARHCAR asFK then. Will it effect the write speed? Does this have the same effect as inserting VARCHAR as FK?

Comment: VARCHAR as PK is a bad way to go. But I dont know how VARCHAR as FK would affect the performance, I think it doesnt as it is not bound by rules that are set for PK.